# What's the difference and when it should be used between 操作、動作、作動、運転、作用

Tags: word-choice, usage

I work as an engineer, and inside the heap of documents that I have been going through.

As an example, there's a lot of sentences that describing how the machine operates, or operation behaviour.

In there, I found a kanji that when it is translated into English. It has a similar meaning, which is kind of confusing.

So between this 操作、動作、作動、運転、作用

What's the difference and when I should use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *to operate*, the following are possible translations.

- Someone(X) operates a machine(Y) XがYを操作する/動作させる/作動させる/運転する
- A machine(Y) operates Yが動作する/作動する/{動作中,作動中,運転中}である

In terms of difference:

- 操作する means more *to manipulate*, so the subject is animate.
- 動作する means *to move*. Talking about machines, it is close to *working* or *being functional*.
- 作動する means close to 動作する, but it sounds more *to start working*. For general usage, 作動 is mostly used for machines while 動作's subject can be animate or inanimate.
- In contexts of operating a machine, 運転する should be mostly synonymous to 操作する. (It may depend on the type of machine.) In general, it means more *to drive (a vehicle)* while 操作する sounds doing something with your fingers.
- 作用する is *to affect*. I can't really imagine it is used as *to operate*. Xの動作がYに作用する would mean *the movement of some part (X) affects the movement of another part (Y)*

Comment: ありがとうございました！While it will take me quite some time to remember the difference. This simple explanation is useful and easy to remember